# representation of sum of squares of a globally positive quadratic function

Tags: polynomials, sum-of-squares-method

Consider the following quadratic function
\begin{equation}
f(y,z)=1697 y^2+57 y z+81 y+407 z^2-6 z+1
\end{equation}
Using first and second derivatives test, we have shown that the global minimum of $f$ occurs at $(y_0,z_0)= (-\frac{66276}{2759467},\frac{24981}{2759467})$ and $f(y_0,z_0)=\frac{346}{2759467}>0$. This leads to $f(y,z)>0$ for all $y,z\in\mathbb{R}$. According to Hilbert's seventeenth problem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_seventeenth_problem), $f(y,z)$ can be represented as sum of squares of other polynomials. How we write $f(y,z)$ as a sum of squares? Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: See [this paper](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=2ahUKEwjvru2AnprpAhWJiqQKHfU6DocQFjAFegQIARAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ens.fr%2F~benoist%2Farticles%2FCarresEMS.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3M66wuQLjj2wYLwcCi3dOF).

Comment: You may find this useful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133141/expressing-a-polynomial-as-a-sum-of-squares

Comment: @Macavity Isn’t that overkill here? The given function is quadratic; this is a conventional exercise in completing squares.

Comment: Are there any restriction on the coefficients of these polynomials? Otherwise, just completing the square a few times will do the trick. If you want to stick to integral coefficients, give [this algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1388421/265466) a try.

Comment: @amd Agreed, this quadratic example is simpler, but the OP referred to a more general problem, hence thought maybe useful.

Answer (score 1):

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 81 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 &  \frac{ 600 }{ 227 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 227 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 692 }{ 227 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 81 }{ 2 }  &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 600 }{ 227 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 81 &  - 6 \\ 
81 & 3394 & 57 \\ 
 - 6 & 57 & 814 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

and so on...

Algorithm discussed at [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 81 &  - 6 \\ 
81 & 3394 & 57 \\ 
 - 6 & 57 & 814 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 81 &  - 6 \\ 
81 & 3394 & 57 \\ 
 - 6 & 57 & 814 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 81 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 81 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 81 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 &  - 6 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 227 }{ 2 }  & 300 \\ 
 - 6 & 300 & 814 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 81 }{ 2 }  & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 81 }{ 2 }  &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 227 }{ 2 }  & 300 \\ 
0 & 300 & 796 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 600 }{ 227 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 81 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 24981 }{ 227 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 600 }{ 227 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 81 }{ 2 }  &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 600 }{ 227 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 227 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 692 }{ 227 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 81 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 24981 }{ 227 }  &  -  \frac{ 600 }{ 227 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 81 &  - 6 \\ 
81 & 3394 & 57 \\ 
 - 6 & 57 & 814 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 81 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 24981 }{ 227 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 600 }{ 227 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 227 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 692 }{ 227 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 81 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 &  \frac{ 600 }{ 227 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 227 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 692 }{ 227 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 81 }{ 2 }  &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 600 }{ 227 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 81 &  - 6 \\ 
81 & 3394 & 57 \\ 
 - 6 & 57 & 814 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$